# AJAX form script isn't executed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to use a form via AJAX, so I got this Code Snippet from another post on stackoverflow. It didn't work, so I added an alert to check, if the script is even executed. That doesn't seem to be the case and I'm wondering why.

```
<head>
    <script src='jquery.js'></script>
    <script>
    var request;

    $("#foo").submit(function(event){

        alert("Hallu");

        if (request) {
            request.abort();
        }

        var $form = $(this);

        var $inputs = $form.find("input, textarea");

        var serializedData = $form.serialize();

        $inputs.prop("disabled", true);

        request = $.ajax({
            url: "/action.php",
            type: "post",
            data: serializedData
        });

        request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
            // Log a message to the console
            console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
        });

        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            // Log the error to the console
            console.error(
                "The following error occurred: "+
                textStatus, errorThrown
            );
        });

        request.always(function () {
            // Reenable the inputs
            $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
        });

        event.preventDefault();
    });


   </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="foo">
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
        <textarea id="msg" name="msg"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Senden" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: please check console and find what errors you are getting ?

Comment: One of the disadvantages of jQuery is that it won't throw an error when you attempt to bind event handlers on an empty jQuery object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is very simple. You do something to `$('#foo')` before it has been loaded. At this point of time JS does not know anything about an object with id="foo", because it is not loaded yet.

Wrap the whole code in `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`.

This should look like this:

```
var request;

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#foo").submit(function(event){

        alert("Hallu");

        if (request) {
            request.abort();
        }

        var $form = $(this);

        var $inputs = $form.find("input, textarea");

        var serializedData = $form.serialize();

        $inputs.prop("disabled", true);

        request = $.ajax({
            url: "/action.php",
            type: "post",
            data: serializedData
        });

        request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
            // Log a message to the console
            console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
        });

        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            // Log the error to the console
            console.error(
                "The following error occurred: "+
                textStatus, errorThrown
            );
        });

        request.always(function () {
            // Reenable the inputs
            $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
        });

        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Please consider using a good IDE, like NetBeans or Eclipse. It helps you to detect unclosed brackets and other stuff.

Comment: I did that and now, the console says "Unexpected end of input"

Comment: I have forgotten to close the last bracket. Please add a `)`. I have edited my post.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Still, there's the unexpected error. It's probably caused by the script itself.

Comment: Paste it please. Maybe we can help you.

Comment: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input"

Comment: Please just copy & paste from my post - I've edited it.

Answer (score 2):

When the script runs, `#foo` does not exist, so there is nothing to bind the event hander to.

Move the script so it appears after the form, or convert it to a function and bind it as a `ready` or `load` event handler.

Comment: place the html above the script and the prevent default command in the start of the function

Comment: There's no need to move the preventDefault call.